# All the UILabels in my UITableViewCell sometimes have a black background color

Tags: iphone, colors, background, label

This happens like once every 100 times I open my app.

Normally all the UILabel work fine and have a white background.

But every once in a while, the app opens and they all have a black background.

Then it's black on black text and you can't read anything.

I've tried setting the backgroundColor to white or clearColor.  Doesn't seem to affect this when it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange that a bug like this only happens 1 in every 100 times. But I'm guessing this is in the simulator? If it doesn't happen on your device, it might be not worth worrying about too much. This especially goes if you're using the 2.2.x simulator with Xcode using the 3.0 SDK. I personally get crashes with the 2.2.1 simulator sometimes, and after Googling a bit, found out it seems to be a pretty common problem. So I just use the 3.0 simulator when that happens.

Otherwise, the only thing I can think of is the [`opaque`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/opaque) setting on the `UITableViewCell`.